# 401 error access twitter using tweepy with proxy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have to use the proxy to get the stream twitter, and here is my code.

```
import twitter, json, urllib2, chardet, tweepy
from tweepy import Stream, OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
proxy = {'http':'http//:127.0.0.1:53899','https':'https://127.0.0.1:53899'}
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxy)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
# setting the OAuth
consumer_key = "OsVDCkR7Y6qoUdpbuglJfuEr0"
consumer_secret = ' tBUEwi3LBpIriTYTCGtqnahdoFSAk6piB48vtDZMNz317xVK6U'
access_token = '3154430460-qwpCD2vHsLt0dOrpTDqZvnFQnY5GUS53iyHJy9p'
access_token_secret = ' dCkLKWoCudTJLIO6ZdsUqQWufyrtZyNCiDotLzncXwjDs'
class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self,data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self,status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
twitterstream = Stream(auth,listener())
# filter the car
twitterstream.filter(track=["car"])
```

And the result is repeating `401` without error showing.

I have checked my time zone setting, and adjusted it to global clock zone, but still not working. Also I changed the time zone on twitter account to UNT. But the 401 stays.

Any thoughts would be helpful !

Answer (score 1):

Change the lines:

```
consumer_secret = ' tBUEwi3LBpIriTYTCGtqnahdoFSAk6piB48vtDZMNz317xVK6U'
#...
access_token_secret = ' dCkLKWoCudTJLIO6ZdsUqQWufyrtZyNCiDotLzncXwjDs'
```

to:

```
consumer_secret = 'tBUEwi3LBpIriTYTCGtqnahdoFSAk6piB48vtDZMNz317xVK6U'
#...
access_token_secret = 'dCkLKWoCudTJLIO6ZdsUqQWufyrtZyNCiDotLzncXwjDs'
```

Comment: OMG, IT WORKED! I have spent the whole weak finding the problem... Thanks bro!